# Удаление пустых строк в R

Tags: r

Допустим у меня есть список: `listt = list(c("best", "ever", "string", "", "or", "", "not"))`, мне нужно удалить все пустые строки в нем.
Я делаю так:
`listt[sapply(listt, nchar) > 0]`, но на выход получаю:

```
[[1]]
[1] "best"   "ever"   "string" ""       "or"     ""       "not"   

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL
```

Не совсем понимаю в чем проблема, буду рад любой помощи, так и объяснению моей проблемы, так и решению изначальной (удаление пустых строк)

Comment: Кажется я понял, что sapply возращает не вектор, а вектор столбец, видимо в этом проблема, но тогда не понятно как это исправить.

Comment: listt[nchar(unlist(listt)) > 0] - сделал так, выражение внутри правильно все возращает, но все равно получается на выходе не то...

Comment: Варианты [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35450478/5812238): 1) [`lapply(l, setdiff, '')`](http://rextester.com/XYFP55898) 2) [`lapply(l, function(x) x[nzchar(x)])`](http://rextester.com/UIQCP80439)

Comment: Да, второй вариант неплохой. Спасибо.

Comment: Но неприятный осадок все равно остался, хочется понять что у меня было не так и что это за волшебная конструкция с nzchar

Comment: Ну подождите кого-нибудь, кто знает `r` (я совсем его не знаю, просто погуглил по запросу "r list remove empty strings")

Comment: Спасибо вам, немного огорчен, что не умею гуглить так как Вы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«проблема» начинается вот с этой конструкции:

```
> list(c("best", "ever", "string", "", "or", "", "not"))
[[1]]
[1] "best"   "ever"   "string" ""       "or"     ""       "not"
```

как видим, в ней список состоит только из **одного** элемента (включающего вектор из семи строк).

судя же по дальнейшим манипуляциям, вам нужен список, состоящий из **семи** элементов. получить его можно, например, заменив функцию `list()` на `as.list()`:

```
> as.list(c("best", "ever", "string", "", "or", "", "not"))
[[1]]
[1] "best"

[[2]]
[1] "ever"

[[3]]
[1] "string"

[[4]]
[1] ""

[[5]]
[1] "or"

[[6]]
[1] ""

[[7]]
[1] "not"
```

из такого списка функция `sapply()` извлечёт именно то, что вы ожидаете:

```
> listt <- as.list(c("best", "ever", "string", "", "or", "", "not"))
> listt[sapply(listt, nchar) > 0]
[[1]]
[1] "best"

[[2]]
[1] "ever"

[[3]]
[1] "string"

[[4]]
[1] "or"

[[5]]
[1] "not"
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот пример:

```
lapply(listt, function(i) i[ nchar(i) > 0 ] )
# [[1]]
# [1] "best"   "ever"   "string" "or"     "not"
```